# Change lower case to upper case in an certain XML tag

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to write a bash script that will change the server inner name to be in upper cases.

I have found many ways to change a certain tag, but since I have two tags with the same name and I want to change only the inner server tag, I did not manage to do it with `sed`.

xml example:

```
<server-list>
  <name>joe</name>
  <server.inner>
    <name>jake</name>
  </server.inner>
</server-list>
```

I have tried without success:

```
sed 's/<server.inner><name>.*/\U&/' <fileToSed
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Choose the right tool first. I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Answer (score 1):

As long as server.inner are not grouped inside each other and the xml file is rather simple, a sed script like this might work:

**script.sed**

```
/<server.inner>/,/<\/server.inner>/ {
   s:<name>(.*)</name>:<name>\U\1\E</name>:gi;
}
```

You would run it like this `sed -rf script.sed your.xml`

**Explanation**

- `/<server.inner>/,/<\/server.inner>/` matches only lines of the `server.inner` tag and applies the sed statements to those lines
- `s:<name>(.*)</name>:<name>\U\1\E</name>:gi;` does the replacement, due to `/` occuring in the closing tag, we use `s:..:..:` instead of `s:..:..:`
- the `(.*) captures the string inside the name tag into the placeholder`\1`
- `\U\1\E` is a gnu sed extension converting the content of the `\1` placeholder to uppercase

For complex xml please follow Cyrus advice and use a special xml tool.

Comment: @EdMorton Changed the script like you suggested. I did not know the `\U ... \E´ feature yet. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Any way to achieve this without GNU-specific sed dialect? I have had similar challenges to the OP's, but I use BSD. I would love to see a portable solution instead of a vendor-specific one.

Comment: @Graham I cant think of an easy way. You might want to look into awk and its `toupper` function.